# Can not find function in reactjs

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, reactjs

I am getting error of `Cannot read property 'clickHandler' of undefined`

```
var FilterableProductTable = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            var rows = [];
            this.props.products.forEach(function(product) {
                if( product.Control == "" || product.Control == undefined) {
                   rows.push(<tr colSpan = "2"  key = {product.Field}><th>{product.Field}</th><td></td></tr>); //rows.push( < ProductHeader product = { product } key = { product.Field } /> );
                }
                else {                           
                    var ControlTag;
                    if(product.Control == "textarea") {
                        ControlTag = <span><textarea rows="4" cols="18" id={ product.id } title={ product.id }></textarea><i className="fa fa-pencil changeSetting" title="Change control"></i></span> 
                    }
                    else if(product.Control == "select") {
                        ControlTag = <span><select style={{width: '60%'}} id={ product.id } title={ product.id }><option></option></select><i className="fa fa-pencil changeSetting" title="Change control"></i></span> 
                    }
                    else {
                        ControlTag=<span><input type="text" id={ product.id } title={ product.id }/><i className="fa fa-pencil changeSetting" title="Change control"></i></span> 
                    }
                rows.push(<tr colSpan = "2" key = {product.Field}><th>{product.Field}</th><td onClick={ this.clickHandler }>{ControlTag}</td></tr>);                          // rows.push( < ProductRow product = { product }  key = { product.Field } />);
                }
            });                
            return ( <table className={'tagsTable'}><tbody>{rows}</tbody></table> )
        },
        clickHandler: function(e){ alert(); }
   });
```

is there something missing in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using forEach loop, so `this` inside loop will not be the component itself.

```
var FilterableProductTable = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            var rows = [];
            var self = this; // <== new code
            this.props.products.forEach(function(product) {              
                // bunch of code..    
                // changed click to onClick={ self.clickHandler }
                rows.push(<td onClick={ self.clickHandler }>{ControlTag}</td>);
                // bunch of code..  
            });
        },
        clickHandler: function(e){ alert(); }
   });
```

Or set scope for forEach loop itself as suggested by [Alexander T.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367138/alexander-t) Indeed i like it better than solution above

```
var FilterableProductTable = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            var rows = [];
            this.props.products.forEach(function(product) {              
                // your code, without any modification
            }, this); // <== notice: this
        },
        clickHandler: function(e){ alert(); }
   });
```

Comment: Damn, one minute too late.

Comment: @Medet Tleukabiluly it is not necessary use additional variable `var self = this;` because you can set `this` for `forEach` callback through second argument `[].forEach(function () { ... }, this)` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 1):

It's because `this` is used inside a forEach function, so it refers to this function, not your React component. Use this little JS trick :

```
var self = this;

this.props.products.forEach(function(product) {
     <td onClick={ self.clickHandler }></td>
}
```